# Replace all html codes by preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all html codes to empty space. I think I should use **preg_replace** function, but I'm not sure how should I do that in case when html codes looks in this way:

```
&#8221;
&#946;

$text="&#946; something &#8221; test..."

$text=preg_replace("&# [what should be here?] ;", " ", $text);

echo $text;
result =  something  test...
```

I think it should be only numeric, because I found only numeric ones here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: I'm not exactly shure what you want to do. Could you give an example?

Comment: What about "named" entities e.g. `&nbsp;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at [strip_tags](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) which does exactly that. However those arent HTML codes, they are called HTML entities.

The [regex](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gims&regex=%28&#%5B0-9%5D%2b;%29&input=”%20sdfasdfasd%20f%20{%20lksdjflsdj) to match what you want looks like this:

`(&#.+?;)`

Its rather simple, look for the `&#` then any repeated character until `;`.

Edit: As Qtax pointed out, they dont have to be numbers. Dot matches all.

Comment: Thanks, that I was looking for. Then code should look like this now: `$text=preg_replace("/&#[0-9]+;/", " ", $text);` ?

Comment: @Lucas, note that this will not match `&#x20;` nor `&amp;` formats.

Comment: Thanks, I changed code: `$text=preg_replace("&#[0-9]+;", " ", $text);`

Comment: @Qtax thanks, edited to allow any character. Not it still doesnt match `&#;` , this is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

HTML character references can be [defined in two ways](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#entities). Assuming that you only want to replace numeric character references, you need a regular expression that parses these formats:

- `&#D;` where D is a decimal number
- `&#xH;` where H is a hexadecimal number

The regex that takes care of both:

```
/&#(\d+|x[\da-f]+);/i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all HTML entities like `&foo;` you could use something like:

```
preg_replace('/&(?:[a-z]+|#x[\da-f]+|#\d+);/i', ' ', $text);
```

If you want to decode them, use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

`&<something>;` is a syntax for HTML entity. If you want to replace all of them, use this regexp:

```
preg_replace('/&.*?;/', '', $subject); // from ampersand till the next semicolon
```

It will replace all HTML entities with an empty string, including `&auml;`, `&x20;` and others